# jcr:MixinTypes not working on cq:widgetCollection node

Tags: aem, acl, jcr

I have a node of type cq:WidgetCollection(assume /apps/damadmin/tabs) and when i apply a permission on this node, a jcr:MixinTypes with value as rep:AccessControllable(AEM default behaviour) is getting added on this node(/apps/damadmin/tabs). So, after this when i try to load the console which has this widget, the whole page is not loading.

Did anyone faced this issue and resolved? Please reply.

Comment: I would suggest checking error.log first to check what is the issue. If you still not figure it out, please provide logs and more info about permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't see any errors in error.log or in my custom logs.